# Formula to compute the number of elapsed days

Tags: c, structure

I am doing a task (from a textbook) that should compute the number of elapsed days between two dates. I can't figure out how days at the end of the formula are computed. In the example from the textbook there are 202 days between August 8, 2004 and February 22, 2005, based on the formula:

```
N=1461 * f(year,month)/4 + 153 * g(month)/5 + day,
where f(year, month) = year -1 if month <=2
                       year    otherwise
and g(month) = month + 13      if month <= 2
               month + 1       otherwise
```

But no indication on how to compute the last variable 'day'. In the above example, the last variable 'day' is equal to 3 for N1 and 21 for N2.

> Where do these numbers come from?

```
N1 = (1461 * 2004) / 4 + (153 * 9)/5 + 3,
N2 = (1461 * 2004) / 4 + (153 * 15)/5 + 21.
```

> Also, how this formula was derived?

Comment: Suspect you have a transcription error from your book to here.

Comment: *"no indication on how to compute the last variable 'day'"* - surely the day, as in day, month, year.

Comment: 1461 is the number of days in 4 years, but it falsely assumes that every 4th year is a leap year.

Comment: I don't get it: where does 3 and 21 come from? I understand that it's a day, but neither August 8th, nor February 22 represent above mentioned numbers. I am confused )

Answer (score 0):

I have written this little program based on the formula, but I still can't figure out how days are being computed (at the end of the formula data.day):

```
// Program to compute the number of elapsed days

#include <stdio.h>

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

int number_of_days (struct date data);

int main (void)
{
    int number1, number2;
    struct date data1;
    struct date data2;

    printf ("Please, enter two dates (mm dd yyyy)");
    scanf  ("%i%i%i  %i%i%i", &data1.month, &data1.day, &data1.year, &data2.month, &data2.day, &data2.year);

    number1 = number_of_days(data1);
    number2 = number_of_days(data2);

    printf("The number of elapsed days is %i\n", number2 - number1);

    return 0;
}

int number_of_days (struct date data)
{
    int number;

    if (data.month <= 2)
        number = (1461 * (data.year - 1)) / 4 + (153 * (data.month + 13)) / 5 + data.day;
    else
        number = (1461 * data.year) / 4 + (153 * (data.month + 1)) / 5 + data.day;

    return number;
}
```